# How to align labels? Python

Tags: python, label

So I have this program where I am supposed to receive certain information from a file and then I must separate it into groups like in a table.

```
Like this:
Name   Sales  #Items
Randy  85     5
Charli 100    10
```

I know how to print it I would usually do this:

```
print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format('Name', 'Sales', '#Items'))
for name, sales, item in list:
    name, age, course = value
    print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(name, sales, item))
```

But that does not work with Labels and the outcome is not aligned. Any solutions?

Comment: What is list variable. Also you would want to change that name because that would prevent you from converting anything to a list. Never use inbuilt keyword as a variable

Comment: List is a list of tuples so [(Randy,85,5),(Charli,100,10)]. The name is lst in the program I just wrote list so it would be easier.

Comment: As @Sujay mentioned you should not use keywords as variable. Apart from that I think your code should work fine and proper aligned.

Comment: I think you need to explain what kind of `Label`. Sounds like it might be GUI framework. If so, which one? And it would be good to see what code is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use keywords as a variable. Also, the variable to be assigned should always be on the left.

```
lists=[('Randy',85,5),('Charli',100,10)]
print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format('Name', 'Sales', '#Items'))
for name, sales, item in lists:
    value=name, sales,item
    print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(name, sales, item))
```

Output

```
Name       Sales      #Items    
Randy      85         5         
Charli     100        10
```

Comment: I know and I understand, but my question is: How do I get the same output in a Label?

Comment: What do you mean same output @AlexJB

Comment: You want to put to have the heading with each student

Comment: No. You know how I used a for loop to get them aligned with print()? I would like to know if there is a way to do the same with Label. Because with the Label, when they show in the Tkinter, they are not aligned.

Comment: If you are using grid then sticky is good for you. If your are using place then the x should be same and for pack you could just pack it to a side

Comment: But I suggest treeview would be more better